# How to increment filename from inside for loop in python?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have eighteen folders in a directory, each of them has four images from a specific region of four larger images that have been cropped into eighteen smaller pieces. I want to remake the four original images and for that I made a code that goes through all the folders in the directory taking the first image from each folder and pasting it in the correct position to make the first image.

```
from PIL import Image
from natsort import natsorted
import os

image_path = "heat_map/"
w1 = 2560
h1 = 2048
dir_list = natsorted(os.listdir(image_path))
for im in range(4):
    output_image = Image.new(mode="RGBA", size=(w1,h1), color="black")
    i=0
    x0 = 0
    y0 = 0
    for folder in dir_list:
        i+=1
        image_list = natsorted(os.listdir(os.path.join(image_path, folder)))
        for item in image_list:
            pathname = os.path.join(image_path, folder)
            piece = Image.open(os.path.join(pathname, item))
            w2, h2 = piece.size
            output_image.paste(piece, (x0,y0))
            piece.close()
            break
        if i == 3:
            x0 =+ w2
            y0 = 0
            continue
        y0 += h2
        if y0<h1:
            continue
        x0 += w2
        y0 = 0    
    output_image.save("output/output_"+str(i)+"_"+str(im)+".png")
    output_image.close()
```

My question is about the third for loop: how do I increment the var "item" even with break at the end of the loop? This var needs to be incremented at the end of the first for loop so that after making the first image, the code starts taking the second image from each folder to build the next image and go on until I have four big images.

Comment: Why do you have a break that makes you exit the for loop at the end of the first iteration in the first place?

Comment: The `break` is not necessary!  It will be almost impossible to make this code work if you leave it there.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille because I can't let the loop iterate through the images, I need to take one of them and go to another folder. Only after going through all the folders will I go back in the first one to get the next image. Hayat`s solution worked perfectly, but thanks for your time anyway!

Comment: If you use a break after the first iteration, then it was never intended to be a loop, and you should have used a simple `if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Added extra variable `j` that controls the count. Follow comments to change as per you need.

```
from PIL import Image
from natsort import natsorted
import os

image_path = "heat_map/"
w1 = 2560
h1 = 2048
dir_list = natsorted(os.listdir(image_path))
for im in range(4):
    output_image = Image.new(mode="RGBA", size=(w1, h1), color="black")
    i = 0
    j = 0
    x0 = 0
    y0 = 0
    for folder in dir_list:
        i += 1
        image_list = natsorted(os.listdir(os.path.join(image_path, folder)))
        for _ in range(len(image_list)):
            pathname = os.path.join(image_path, folder)
            piece = Image.open(os.path.join(pathname, image_list[j]))
            w2, h2 = piece.size
            output_image.paste(piece, (x0, y0))
            piece.close()
            j += 1  # increments everytime
            break
        if i == 3:
            x0 = + w2
            y0 = 0
            continue
        y0 += h2
        if y0 < h1:
            continue
        x0 += w2
        y0 = 0
        if j >= len(image_list): # breaks the loop once done with all image-list
            break
    output_image.save("output/output_" + str(i) + "_" + str(im) + ".png")
    output_image.close()
```

Comment: I had to make some adjustments for my needs but it worked like a charm. Thank you so much!

Comment: @eduarfa Pleasure. Please upvote if helps.